# Python: sorting a zip based on length and weight

Tags: python, sorting

In Python 2, assume we have two lists:

```
list1 = [["A"],["A","B"],["B","D"],["C"],["A","B","D"]]
list2 = [5,10,10,15,10]
```

I want to sort list1 based on list2 (weights) in descending and whenever the weight of two items are the same (for example both x = ["A","B","D"] and y = ["B","D"] have the weight of 10), the one with larger length comes first. For list1 and list 2, I want the output to be like:

`[["C"], ["A","B","D"], ["A","B"],["B","D"],["A"]`]

How is it possible?

What I know is that we can sort them based on only size by first defining

```
zipped = zip(list1,list2)
```

and then:

```
zipped.sort(key=lambda t: t[1],reverse=True)
```

Comment: I think you mean you want to sort `list1` based on `list2` and not the way you have written it.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid You are right. Edited.

Comment: Good first step. Now what have you tried for the rest?

Comment: I assume you're using Python 2, since `zip` returns an iterator in Python 3.

Comment: @JulienBernu For the second step, I was thinking of extracting the item having the same weight. Then, define a new weight which is equal to length of each item and sort them based on new weights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to sort by several parameters your `key` function should return a tuple:

```
In [6]: sorted(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda x: (x[1], len(x[0])), reverse=True)
Out[6]: 
[(['C'], 15),
 (['A', 'B', 'D'], 10),
 (['A', 'B'], 10),
 (['B', 'D'], 10),
 (['A'], 5)]
```

The `key=lambda x: (x[1], len(x[0]))` should be read as *"firstly order by the weight in the x[1] and then  by the length of a list in x[0]"*.

In order to retrieve first element from each tuple you may wrap the result into a list comprehension:

```
In [7]: [x[0] for x in sorted(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda x: (x[1], len(x[0])), reverse=True)]
Out[7]: [['C'], ['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'D'], ['A']]
```

Comment: @PM2Ring, sure, but this is also a part of a Python's zen: *"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."* :)

Comment: @soon Thanks, I didn't know about the fact that we can give multiple criteria  in "key".

Comment: @m0_as, actually, there is no magic at all - just try to compare some tuples in REPL, e.g. : `(1, 2) > (1, 3)`, `(1, 2) > (1, 1)` and `(2, 2) > (1, 10)`

Comment: @soon I see. Good observation.

Answer (score 4):

Your key function needs to tell `sort` to check the length of the `list1` item when the `list2` weights are identical. You can do that by making the key a tuple, like this:

```
list1 = [["A"],["A","B"],["B","D"],["C"],["A","B","D"]]
list2 = [5,10,10,15,10]

zipped = zip(list1,list2)

zipped.sort(key=lambda t: (t[1], len(t[0])), reverse=True)

print(list(zip(*zipped)[0]))
```

**output**

```
[['C'], ['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'D'], ['A']]
```

---

FWIW, here's a version that will work in Python 3 and Python 2. My previous code won't work in Python 3 because the Python 3 `zip` returns an iterator, not a list.

```
zipped = zip(list1, list2)
zipped = sorted(zipped, key=lambda t: (t[1], len(t[0])), reverse=True)
newlist = [t[0] for t in zipped]
print(newlist)
```

Comment: @soon Thanks for your complete response.